# How to match usb device UUID to MODEL and VENDOR?

Tags: usb-drive, lsblk

I'm working on a tool for managing USB devices attached to my machine.

At one point I need to match UUIDs to vendor and model, so I used the following command:

```
# lsblk -o UUID,MODEL,VENDOR,TRAN
5A26-0601                            USB3.0 CRW   -SD Generic- usb
                                     Voyager 3.0      Corsair  usb
7936-E126
```

Ultimately it has to work bidirectionally: sometimes I only have an UUID and I need to find MODEL/VENDOR, sometimes I have MODEL or VENDOR and I need to find all matching UUIDs.

For the device `5A26-0601` all is on order - data fields are all in one line and I can use `grep`, `cut`, `awk` etc. to my heart's content.

Not so for the other device - for some reason UUID is one line below the rest of the information. This remains true if `7936-E126` is the only device attached. UUID's length cannot be the reason, because both of them contain 9 characters.

If I try adding an argument with device's location I can only get useful information about `5A26-0601`:

```
# lsblk -o UUID,MODEL,VENDOR,TRAN /dev/disk/by-uuid/5A26-0601
UUID                                 MODEL            VENDOR   TRAN
5A26-0601                            USB3.0 CRW   -SD Generic- usb
# lsblk -o UUID,MODEL,VENDOR,TRAN /dev/disk/by-uuid/7936-E126
UUID                                 MODEL VENDOR TRAN
7936-E126
```

How can I get all the data I need for all my devices? Is `lsblk` right tool for the job and I'm simply using it wrong, should I use something else, or that's the best I can get and I must sharpen up my scripting skills and try to parse the results I'm getting now?

It has to work in embedded environment, so I prefer to use as simple tools as possible.

Comment: can you use `blkid` instead? this command will format and give u only the values `blkid -s UUID -o value`

Comment: `blkid` gives me UUID, label, and filesystem. I don't see how can I use that information to connect UUID with model and vendor. Is there any way to call `blkid` to print those fields? I checked help and man pages and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to solve my problem with `udevadm`.

MODEL and VENDOR can be obtained by querying properties and grepping relevant information:

```
# udevadm info --query property /dev/disk/by-uuid/7936-E126 | grep "ID_VENDOR=\|ID_MODEL="
ID_MODEL=Voyager_3.0
ID_VENDOR=Corsair
# udevadm info --query property /dev/disk/by-uuid/5A26-0601 | grep "ID_VENDOR=\|ID_MODEL="
ID_MODEL=USB3.0_CRW_-SD
ID_VENDOR=Generic-
```

So now I can easily and unambiguously access MODEL and VENDOR for a given UUID.

For now the only way to reverse this process is to iterate over all devices, and select only those with property `ID_BUS=usb` and matching VENDOR or MODEL, but given the scope of the original question this answer is sufficient.